# Check the value of FSL_M_Control in the MicroBlaze

Tags: c, xilinx, microblaze

I wrote a hardware accelerator which communicates with a MicroBlaze over FSL. In the Microblaze C code I would like to use `putfsl()` in a loop until the hardware accelerator signals the MicroBlaze that it should exit the loop:

```
while( <FSL_M_Control is not 1> )
{
    putfsl(*foo, 0);
    foo++;
}
```

Is it possible to get the value of `FSL_M_Control` and use it to exit the loop? If it is how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we're clear, you mean `FSL_M_Control` of the IP, which is `FSL_S_Control` on the microblaze, right? Because `FSL_M_Control` is driven by the microblaze...

The fast answer is "no".

However, the functions `cgetfsl` and `getfsl` will make a read and report *FSL_S_Control* through the carry bit, meaning they set the carry bit if *FSL_S_Control* = '0' when you use `cgetfsl` and vice-versa. Keep in mind that the FSL transaction has to be valid, i.e. *FSL_S_Exist* must be driven otherwise these functions blocks. You can verify the carry bit with the macro `fsl_isinvalid`.

```
do {
    putfsl(*foo++, 0);
    getfsl(dummy, 0);
    fsl_isinvalid(dummy); /* fsl_isinvalid doesn't return a value, this assign the carry bit to the variable dummy. This has for effect to put the value of FSL_S_Control into dummy */
 } while(!dummy);
```

Comment: By `FSL_M_Control` I mean the control signal wihich goes from the IP to the MicroBlaze. With your solution, for each `putfsl` my IP would need to write a value to the FIFO which goes to the MicroBlaze, right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the code will block. Another possible solution is to drive the full instead. You can check if the write is successful with ˋfsl_isinvalid`, and use ˋnputfsl` to prevent your code from blocking. For that solution, use ˋnputfsl` and remove the ˋgetfsl` from my code.